# Spring batch FileItemWriter not creating file at correct path

Tags: java, linux, spring, websphere, spring-batch

I have a spring batch service containing a FileItemReader,FileItemProcessor and FileItemWriter.When creating the FileItemWriter I have to set the Resource that will be my output file.

I am running the batch service on websphere on a Linux machine.The problem is if I set the resource as new FileSystemResource(new File("opt\temp1\myFile.txt")), the path of the file created is "**/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/\opt\temp\myFile.txt**" which is not what I want.The path where I want to put the file is "\opt\temp\myFile.txt" on the linux file system.Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?.

Please see below the snippet where I am doing this.I am extending the FileItemWriter and overriding the open method to set the resource. Many Thanks.

```
@Override
    public void open (ExecutionContext context)
    {
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID ().toString ();
        String filePath = fileLocation + fileName;
        resource = new FileSystemResource (new File (filePath));
        setResource (resource);
        super.open (context);
    }
```

fileLocation = "\opt\temp\", 
fileName="myFile.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using backslashes in the value of `fileLocation`. They are valid file name characters in linux. You should change the path to `/opt/temp/`.

Comment: Thankss Steffen.You are right.I have corrected it.But what I don't understand is why it is creating the file relative to server path "/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/\opt\temp\myFile.txt".

Comment: That's because you didn't use an absolute path but a relative one. The [docs for `File#getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath--) tell you how the absolute path gets constructed.

Comment: @Cheeta It would be nice to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Yes I read the docs regarding File.getAbsolutePath.But in it it says "On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory.", so this means I will still get "/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/opt/temp/myFile.txt" but in db I am saving only "opt/temp/myFile.txt" and trying to access the file programatically later on.

Comment: Why don't you add the preceding slash? Then you have an absolute path.

Comment: I am sorry I did not get you.

Comment: Store `/opt/temp/myFile.txt` instead of `opt/temp/myFile.txt`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80881/discussion-between-cheeta-and-steffen-kreutz).